# Centripetal force in Unity to achieve perfect circular path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

Why I had to add `-0.5f` to `NForce` to achieve a perfectly circular path by `ball2` if The magnitude of the centrifugal force is equal and opposite to the magnitude of the centripetal force why `-1` did not work?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Ball1;
    public Rigidbody Ball2;
    public float Velocity;
    public LineRenderer Line;


    private void Start()
    {
        // Set up the Line Renderer component
        Line.positionCount = 0;
        Line.startWidth = 0.1f;
        Line.endWidth = 0.1f;
    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Calculate the distance vector between the Ball1 and Ball2
        Vector3 Ball1Position = Ball1.transform.position;
        Vector3 Ball2Position = Ball2.transform.position;


        Vector3 r = Ball1Position - Ball2Position;
        Vector3 VelocityVector = Vector3.Cross(r.normalized, Vector3.up) * Velocity;
        Vector3 Force = (Ball2.mass * (Velocity * Velocity) / r.magnitude) * r.normalized;
        Vector3 NForce = -0.5f *Force;


        Ball2.AddForce(NForce);
        Ball2.AddForce(Force);

        Ball2.velocity = VelocityVector;

        Line.positionCount++;
        Line.SetPosition(Line.positionCount - 1, Ball2Position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding force to ball2, what changes its velocity, but then you set the velocity directly (`Ball2.velocity = VelocityVector;`), so `AddForce` is not supposed to have any effect at all. Instead, you should use only one way to change velocity.

Here is code that uses `AddForce` to achieve circular path:

```
private void Start()
{
    // Set up the Line Renderer component
    Line.positionCount = 0;
    Line.startWidth = 0.1f;
    Line.endWidth = 0.1f;

    // Initialize velocity
    Ball2.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Calculate the distance vector between the Ball1 and Ball2
    Vector3 Ball1Position = Ball1.transform.position;
    Vector3 Ball2Position = Ball2.transform.position;

    Vector3 r = Ball1Position - Ball2Position;
    Vector3 Force = (Ball2.mass * (Velocity * Velocity) / r.magnitude) * r.normalized;

    Ball2.AddForce(Force);

    Line.positionCount++;
    Line.SetPosition(Line.positionCount - 1, Ball2Position);
}
```

You don't need to apply centrifugal force and VelocityVector, because centripetal force does everything, but you have to set velocity of ball at start. However, it creates small fluctuactions in path, so it won't be perfect circle.